# how to get values of columns where is has value as TRUE

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way where i can get only the columns where the value is TRUE.
I am unsure on how to get it as the column name could be anything.Please suggest.Thanks.

```
SQL> select * from v$pwfile_users where username='REDOSHIP';

USERNAME                       SYSDB SYSOP SYSAS SYSBA SYSDG SYSKM     CON_ID
------------------------------ ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----------
REDOSHIP                       FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE          0
```

Comment: A SELECT returns a fixed set of columns, which is decided before data is read.

Comment: maybe you can use PIVOT to transform your columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `select` returns a fixed set of columns.  You could concatenate the column names together, using a `case` expression, though:

```
select pu.*,
       (case when SYSDB = 'TRUE' then 'SYSDB;' end ||
        case when SYSOP = 'TRUE' then 'SYSOP;' end ||
        case when SYSAS = 'TRUE' then 'SYSAS;' end ||
        case when SYSBA = 'TRUE' then 'SYSBA;' end ||
        case when SYSDG = 'TRUE' then 'SYSDG;' end ||
        case when SYSKM = 'TRUE' then 'SYSKM;' end
       ) as true_columns
from v$pwfile_users pu
```